# Android - How to send subsequent views to back

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm adding some views to a LinearLayout with a slight overlap in the top, here is the code:

```
viewHolder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
for (int i = 0; i < conversation.getPreviousMessages().length; i++) {
    View messageView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_previous_message_row, null);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, -5, 0, 0);

    viewHolder.linearLayout.addView(messageView, layoutParams);
}
```

In this code some views are added to layout in order A, B, C, with A to the back and C to the front.

I would like to reverse the order, making A to the front and C to the back.

I have tried [this](http://abhishek347.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/android-development-bringtofront-and-sendtoback-on-view/), but nothing happens.

How can I reach this?
Please, could you people bring me some code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some punches against the wall, I finally found a solution:

1.- I changed the layout from being a LinearLayout to being a RelativeLayout because bringChildToFront has a weird behavior among LinearLayout.

2.- After adding the view to the RelativeLayout, I iterated backwards over the views and I made a bringChildToFront.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < conversation.getPreviousMessages().length; i++) {
     View messageView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_previous_message_row, null);
     messageView.setId(99+i);

     viewHolder.relativeLayout.addView(messageView);

     if (i > 0) {
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         layoutParams.setMargins(0, -5, 0, 0);
         layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 99+i-1);

         messageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
     }
 }

 for (int i = viewHolder.relativeLayout.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     viewHolder.relativeLayout.bringChildToFront(viewHolder.relativeLayout.getChildAt(i));
 }
```

I hope it help someone.

Answer (score 1):

There is the capability to change the z-order of a view if that is the question that you are asking.  And if so desired, you can usually get the effect of using the View.bringToFront() capabilities within that class.

[View.bringToFront](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29)

Comment: Although not typically used often while coding on my part, occasionally you will need to do a trick here or there that could involve calling it at the right time on your views, or being sure to invalidate. [bringToFront() issues](http://abhishek347.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/android-development-bringtofront-and-sendtoback-on-view/)