# Android - Placing one layout on top of another layout

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to place one layout in top of another. I can do it but there is a problem in a case. Let me describe it first :
Here is my layout codes:

```
<RelativeLayout>        
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are other things but they are not necessary here . If i run code with these two view works fine. But if i setVisibility(GONE) for the "smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing" in my onCreate() or onResume() method on my Activity. It don't show at all. Though i can see the visibility of that "smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing" on my program and it show it is visible but i don't see it on my screen. I think it is overlapped by the "largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing" . What do you think and how can i solve this matter?

Complete View heirarchy: 
[image: My complete view heirarchy]
Here is my code part:

```
    private LinearLayout smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing, largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing;
private VideoCallImageRenderView smallPlayerGLView, largePlayerGLView;

 private void initVideoRenderer() {
    Constants.debugLog(TEST_TAG, "initVideoRenderer");
    Constants.debugLog(TAG, "initVideoRenderer");
    smallPlayerGLView = new VideoCallImageRenderView(this);
    largePlayerGLView = new VideoCallImageRenderView(this);


    VideoCallCamera.getInstance().startCamera();
    VideoCallCamera.getInstance().cameraCallBack(largePlayerGLView, this);
    isOwnSurfaceViewLarge = true;

    largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing.addView(largePlayerGLView);
    largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing.setOnClickListener(this);

    smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing.addView(smallPlayerGLView);
    smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing.setOnClickListener(this);

    smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Comment: you've set `layout_height = match_parent` for the second layout..

Comment: i need to show the second layout on full screen so i set this. What's the problem on it?

Comment: If the 2nd layout occupies the full screen then naturally the first one will be overlapped by it

Comment: i will add some screenshot soon about the problem

Comment: @akash93 If i don't change visibility of the first layout. Both shows. But i change the visibility to GONE, it create problems. It don't show again

Comment: @akash93 now check this out. I have added my code part

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of:

```
<RelativeLayout>        
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation as root layout. And for your large layout have height of 0dp and weight 1 - it will make your large layout to occupy all available space - and it will be under small layout.
Something like the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">        
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/smallVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/largeVideoRenderLayoutOutgoing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually mylayout is more complex and layered. I am posting my view heirarchy.

Comment: see my new edit please. I have added my detail view heirarchy here.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout width and height from match parent to wrap content.
Or when you make the view invisible call bringToFront() method for the other view.
You should check [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555170/android-how-to-send-subsequent-views-to-back)